# Word Count with Ruby

Tags: ruby, html-parsing

I am trying to figure out a way to count a words in a particular string that contains html.

Example String:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Is there a way in Ruby to count the words in between the p tags? Or any tag for that matter?

Examples:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<li>Hello World</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit (here is my working code)

Controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pages = Page.find(:all)
    @word_count = []
  end

end
```

View:

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>

        <%  page.current_state.elements.each do |el| %>
            <% @count = Hpricot(el.description).inner_text.split.uniq.size  %>
            <% @word_count << @count %>
        <% end %>

            <li><strong>Page Name: <%= page.slug %> (Word Count: <%= @word_count.inject(0){|sum,n| sum+n } %>)</strong></li>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
require 'hpricot'
content = "<p>Hello World...."
doc = Hpricot(content)
doc.inner_text.split.uniq
```

Will give you:

```
[
  [0] "Hello",
  [1] "World"
]
```

(sidenote: the output is formatted with [awesome_print](http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html) that I warmly recommend)

Comment: I suggest you move the code to a dedicated helper function at some point. It will make it easier to unit-test it and reuse it.

Comment: How do you go about doing that? I am new to Rails

Comment: Since Hpricot is dead, you can do exactly the same thing with `Nokogiri::HTML` instead of `Hpricot`

Answer (score 2):

Sure

1. Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML/XML and XPath to find the element and its text value.
2. Split on whitespace to count the words

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like Hpricot to remove the HTML, then it's just a case of counting words in plain text.

Here is an example of stripping the HTML: http://underpantsgnome.com/2007/01/20/hpricot-scrub/

Answer (score 0):

First start with something able to parse HTML like [Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/), then use simple regular expression to do what you want (you can merely split over spaces and then count for example)